# Copy records and related records over in a MySQL database (stored procedure or function)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am thinking that a stored procedure/function will be the best solution for this, but I am open to suggestions.

I want to duplicate a master record, and duplicate all of its associated records at the same time. Consider the following example setup:

```
TABLE 1    TABLE 2     TABLE 3
-------    ----------  ----------
id (PK)    id (PK)     id (PK)
data1      t1_id (FK)  t2_id (FK)
data2      data1       data1
data3      data2       data2
```

Looking at the schema above, you can see that `TABLE 1` is the master table. I want to copy that, along with its child records in `TABLE 2` and its grandchild records in `TABLE 3`.

When this is done, the PK's (of which some are auto_increment, and some are dynamically generated) will need to be updated. When this happens, the Foreign Keys in the related tables will need updating also.

Is there a stored procedure/function that can do this with some ease compared to what I am trying to do now? [select everything into a multidimensional array, and then foreaching, foreaching, foreaching and more foreaching over the data to do inserts and whatnot].

Comment: this is an ondemand process, not something that happens as a method of auditing inserts.

Comment: i am a bit confuse here. is it a one time process or you want to replicate it whenever there's a change in the master table?

Comment: there could be many changes made to the master table, and then when an administrator decides to replicate the data - he kicks off the task to do it.

Comment: in your way, how do you propose to spot the updates? with a timestamp?